# How do I edit an Audio CDs Artist and Title in Dolphin?

Tags: audio-cd

I am running a mostly fresh install of Fedora 14 KDE spin.  I installed lame from rpmfusion to get mp3 support in Dolphin, but the CD I put in comes up with the wrong information.  This isn't surprising since it is an independent release of a band I like, and is probably not in the CDDB.  I am sure this is easy, but I dont know how to correct the information.  I cannot open the virtual 'CDDB Information.txt' and right-click doesn't get me anywhere.  Is there a package that needs to be there that I may have not installed yet?

Comment: seems like this might get more answers / fit better on SuperUser...

Answer (score 1):

[Ex Falso](http://code.google.com/p/quodlibet/) can do this for batches of mp3 files. It's what I use under GNOME:

[image]

I'm not sure how an audio CD differs, but if it does, K3B *definitely* has the tools to do this. I'd be amazed if it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled across this question because I had the same problem.
This is specific to Dolphin file browser which supports copying CDs by Drag&Drop.

The easiest way seems to edit the file in ~/.cddb
CDDB caches its requested information in a file named after the CDs hash (?). After you have edited the file, you need to close and reopen the CD in Dolphin.

You can find the right file by searching the hash from the configuration file in the virtual CD folder in ~/.cddb